# Using a sieve to find number of divisors but only for n^2

Tags: python

Normally I use the following code to find the number of divisors up until a given n (tau function):

```
L=[0 for i in range(N+1)]
for i in range(1,N+1):
    for j in range(i, N+1,i):
        L[j]+=1
print L
```

Which outputs

```
[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4]
```

But what if I want to output divisors for n^2 instead? Right now it's looking at n=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, but I want to change it so it's actually looking at 0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100 (no need to mess with any other numbers).

The output should look like:

```
[0, 1, 3, 3, 5, 3, 9, 3, 7, 5, 9]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you want something like this?

```
>>> [sum(i**2 % j == 0 for j in range(1, i**2 + 1)) for i in range(11)]
[0, 1, 3, 3, 5, 3, 9, 3, 7, 5, 9]
```

Or more generally

```
>>> def divisors(start, end, trans=lambda x:x):
...     return [sum(i % j == 0 for j in range(1, i + 1)) for i in (trans(t) for t in range(start, end+1))]
... 
>>> divisors(0, 10, lambda x: x**2)
[0, 1, 3, 3, 5, 3, 9, 3, 7, 5, 9]
>>> divisors(0, 10)
[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Problem is that this is basically doing the same as "messing with the other numbers" in terms of complexity, but just not doing anything with them due to the modulus. I'm trying not to iterate up to i**2.

Comment: Revision actually gives me the error "int' object is not callable"

Comment: @AOAOne what did you call it with?

Comment: divisors(0, 10, lambda x: x**2)

Comment: Not sure what to say other than that `>>> divisors(0, 10, lambda x: x**2)
[0, 1, 3, 3, 5, 3, 9, 3, 7, 5, 9]` works for me...I'm using python 2.7 maybe you are using a different version?

Comment: I just copied and pasted both definition lines from my post into the console and ran divisors(0, 10, lambda x: x**2) and it worked.  Perhaps a typo?

Comment: Strange >.< I think maybe it's tripping up over the sum() portion. Is there another way to rewrite it?

Comment: "int" object is not callable makes me think that you have () after an int somewhere in your code...it's possible you have variables defined that conflict with those in my method.  I doubt it is sum, I'll look at that in a bit.

Comment: Will mark as answer regardless because I am sure the problem is on my end somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how big `n` is, Nolen's answer may suffice (to be fair your original code isn't optimized to begin with). However, it is worth noting what `n**2` *is*. If we can factorize a number, say `10`, we get that:

```
10    = (2**1)*(5**1)
10**2 = (2**(1+1))*(5**(1+1)) = (2**2)*(5**2)
```

i.e. the number in the exponent in the prime factorization simply doubles. Assuming you can already find the prime factorization of a number `n` (which your code can be modified for), the number of divisors can be found for `n**2` by (pseudocode)

```
div  := (list of divisors of n)
div2 := (a list with two copies of div)
loop through all combinations div2:
      if combo <= sqrt(n): keep unique
```

If we did this for `10` we would get:

```
div  := (1,2,5,10)
div2 := (1,2,5,10,1,2,5,10)
keep := (1,2,5,10,2*2,2*5) 
unique_keep := (1,2,4,5,10)
```

Each of the numbers in `unique_keep` divide into `10**2=100` thus they have a corresponding factor as well, except for the singular case of the 10 which is it's own factor. This gives as nine the divisors:

```
1 -> 100
2 -> 50
4 -> 25
5 -> 20
10 -> 10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the prime factors of a number, it's just as easy to calculate the number of factors it has as it is to calculate the factors of it's square (or, indeed, any power).

```
def factor_count(N,power):
    factor_count = list()
    for n in range(N+1):
        prime = 2
        prime_factors = list()
        exponents = list()
        while n > 1:
            while (n / prime) % 1 == 0:
                if prime not in prime_factors:
                    prime_factors.append(prime)
                    exponents.append(1)
                else:
                    exponent = exponents.pop()+1
                    exponents.append(exponent)
                n /= prime
            prime += 1
        factors = 1
        for x in exponents:
            factors *= power*x+1
        factor_count.append(factors)
    print(factor_count)
```

Also, I'll note that my program differs from yours as to how many factors zero has. It's simple to modify the code to account for this but as divisors are often defined over the natural numbers anyway, it's just as easy to ignore it altogether.

To give you an idea of how efficient this is compared to the other answers given:

```
power_factors(1000,2000000000)                                        #evaluates almost instantly despite having an exponent of 2 billion
[sum(i**2 % j == 0 for j in range(1, i**2 + 1)) for i in range(1001)] #I got fed up of waiting before it managed to finish even with just an exponent of 2
```